# Sort multidimensional array by value with a condition

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Sorting a multidimensional array by value is fairly easy and has been answered multiple times already here

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['field'] - $b['field'];
});
```

The problem I am having now, is that I need another condition. Let's imagine I have an array with 10 cars and 10 motorcycles. These cars and motorcycles are each an array/object with values containing a field `speed`. Like

```
$car1 = [
    'speed' => 100,
    'type' => 'car'
]
$car2 = [
    'speed' => 120,
    'type' => 'car'
]
$car3 = [
    'speed' => 180,
    'type' => 'car'
]
$motorcycle1 = [
    'speed' => 80,
    'type' => 'motorcycle'
]
```

Those are all stored in one array

```
$vechicles = [$car1, $car2, $car3, $motorcycle1]
```

What I now want to do is to sort by speed. Which is, as I said, easy

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['speed'] - $b['speed'];
});
```

The problem I am facing now, is, that independent of the speed value, at least every third vehicle MUST be a motorcycle. It can be, that the first entries are motorcycles, doesn't matter, but it can't be all cars. It always have to be at least one motorcycle. Doesn't matter here if it's 1, 2 or 3 motorcycles. 
So in the end it should look like this

```
$finalArray = [$car3, $car2, $motorcycle1, $car1];
```

As you can see, while `$car1` is faster than `$motorcycle1`, the motorcycle comes earlier.

The thing is, when I have two different arrays

```
$cars = [$car1, $car2, $car3]
```

and

```
$motorcycles = [$motorcycle1]
```

I can simply splice it in, like

```
array_splice($cars, 2, 0, $motorcycles[0]);
```

But then I got the problem that I can't sort it by speed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, easiest solution

```
$vehicles = [...]; // sorted by speed already

$count = count($vehicles);
$temp = 0;

foreach($vehicles as $key => $veh){

    if(is_car($veh)){
        $temp++;
    }else{
        $temp = 0;
    }

    if($temp == 3){

        for($i = $key + 1; $i<=$count; $i++){

            if(is_motorcycle($vehicles[$i])){

                array_splice($vehicles, $key, 0, $vehicles[$i]);
                break;

            }

        }
        $temp = 0;

    }

}
```

Obviously this is not working code, I just wrote it to illustrate my idea, if you think you can benefit from it, happy tweaking! :P

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try it out and then come back

Comment: @Musterknabe I think the biggest issue you may run into is internal pointers when splicing the array while iterating over it. I'm not sure how that's going to work out.

Comment: Awesome! Works. I modified it like this (now with my real code)

http://pastebin.com/DN1dRZX3

:)